# What to set for SQLITE_CFLAGS and SQLITE_LIBS during automake compilation?

Tags: configure, proj

I was trying to compile proj in mingw environment without internet. I cross compiled SQLITE in Ubuntu, now I want to compile PROJ library in my windows environment.

The `./configure` is failing with error that SQLITE is not available.

I can give the path of SQLITE_LIBS as the `sqlite/lib` folder, I don't know if it is correct. What should be the input for SQLITE_CFLAGS?

Answer (score 1):

The content of  `SQLITE_CFLAGS` is your sqlite include directory path, for example `/opt/sqlite-3.28.0/include`.

However, make sure that you have not only `libsqlite3` installed, but that you have `libsqlite3-dev` as well:

```
sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev
```

Otherwise, many `configure` files will try to find the directory and fail with `SQLITE_CFLAGS` location errors.